# Bar Widths in Interactive Altair Graphs

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

How do I make the bars as wide as an entire day? Right now the bars are more like lines demarcating the *start* of the day. Do I switch from bar marks to rectangle marks? Do I toy with band scales? Or do I force binning without modifying the data?

Right now the bars are too thin. Because the graph is interactive I can't set the bar width; width is zoom-independent. Zoom too far out and the bars start overlapping. Zoom too far in and they look like lines again.

Days are on the x-axis. Labels shouldn't change. The graph is interactive and its width is fixed. Blank space between bars should reflect missing days and not be filled with bar.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

c1 = np.random.randint(1,6, size=15)
c2 = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-01-15")
df = pd.DataFrame({"day": c2, "value": c1})
df = df.drop([2, 5,6,7,13])
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(alt.X("day:T"), alt.Y("value")).interactive(bind_y=False).properties(width=800)
```

[image: example of thin bars]

And ideally, when the bar fills the entire day the day marker should be centered on the bar (rather than at the beginning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using a [timeUnit](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html#user-guide-timeunit-transform) with an [ordinal encoding](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types). That is, replace

```python
alt.X("day:T")
```

with

```python
alt.X("date(day):O")
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Depending on the axis labels you want, you can use the `monthdate` or `yearmonthdate` timeUnits instead.

If you want the axis to still be interactive, ordinal encodings are not an option. In this case, another option is to specify the bar widths using the `X` and `X2` encodings, along with a calculate transform to define the limits. For example:

```python
alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    day = "toDate(datum.day)",
    start = "datum.day - 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000",  # -12 hours in milliseconds
    end = "datum.day + 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000",    # +12 hours in milliseconds
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("start:T"),
    alt.X2("end:T"),
    alt.Y("value")
).interactive(bind_y=False).properties(width=800)
```

[image]

Comment: The problems with ordinal encoding is that the missing days are discarded and the graph is no longer interactive. How well do day timeUnits work with ordinal encoding across multiple months when the numbers repeat?

Comment: If you have multiple months, you can use the monthdate time unit. If you have months spanning multiple years, you can use the yearmonthdate time unit.

Comment: I've noticed that you can do `alt.X("date(day):T")` which supports interactivity and missing values. Of course the data is still continuous so band scaling isn't an option. I like `yearmonthdate` but wish it would only show the year on year boundaries, include weekdays in the labels, center the labels to the day, and only show one label per data-point when zoomed-in. Which for the most part also applies to `X`/`X2` encoding. I'm going to have a look at the time format docs.

Comment: I'll just ask another question instead.